# Как происходит проверка условия с сложным выражением на си

Tags: c

Думаю лучше всего начать с примера чтобы стало сразу понятно.

Вот условие:

```
if(pop(&Stack_Zm) == CRZ &&  pop(&Stack_Zm) == 'z' && pop(&Stack_Zm) == 'r')
```

Выполнение с права налево или с лева на право ? Сначала проверяется pop(&Stack_Zm) == CRZ после pop(&Stack_Zm) == 'z' после pop(&Stack_Zm) == 'r' или наоборот? И нет ли зависимостей от компилятора или версии языка ?

Comment: Конечный автомат - finite state machine. "Магазинная память" если перевести с русского на русский - стек.

Comment: «автомата с магазинной памятью» — это «Pushdown automaton». хинт для перевода любых устоявшихся терминов: открываешь википедию и смотришь интервики на нужном языке... «боевой» реализации ни у кого не будет т.к. практической пользы от них как с козла молока...

Comment: Не стоит менять вопрос, лучше удалить и задать новый

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для логических выражений используется сокращенное вычисление. Т.е.

```
 (pop(&Stack_Zm) == CRZ
```

если это ложно - все, вычисления завершены, остальные условия не проверяются. Истинно - проверяется

```
 pop(&Stack_Zm) == 'z'
```

если это ложно - все, вычисления завершены, остальные условия не проверяются. Истинно - проверяется

```
pop(&Stack_Zm) == 'r'
```

Просто если в `&&` ложно хоть одно - то результат точно ложен.

Вычисления слева направо, и сокращенные вычисления - все это есть в стандарте, это не оптимизация.